# Как сделать автоматическое разрешение конфликтов git?

Tags: git

У меня есть три ветки в репозитории.

```
master
slave 1
slave 2
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, что бы при появлении конфликтов всегда выбирался вариант master ?

```
git checkout slave 1
git merge master
```

(появляется конфликт и автоматически выбирается вариант master ветки)

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1125639/1785760)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Git есть понятия стратегия слияния [(официальная документация>Выбор “нашей” или “их” версий](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

```
git checkout slave 1
git merge -Xours master
```

Можно указывать как разово (как в коде выше), так и настроить через атрибуты репозитория.

Аналогичная опция может быть использована и с командой `git merge-file`.

Comment: Спасибо. Это очень помогло. У меня ещё один вопрос появился. Могли бы вы подсказать по нему ?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132794/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-package-json-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-git

Comment: Я постараюсь вечером ответить